# how to keep special characters in df column names in R?

Tags: r, character, names

I'm processing hundreds of MS excel sheets with R (and gdata), in order to save their data in a database.  Unfortunately some (actually a lot) column names contain signs like "+", "-", and others, which are then replaced by "." (dots) in the data frame column names I get.
My question is : how can I keep these signs ?

(I need them to match these names afterward with another source.)

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you share the code about how you're reading the excel files, we can be more specific in our help.  However, many reading functions have a `check.names` argument.  Set it to `FALSE` and the names will stay just like they are.

Comment: Thank you @Justin, that's exactly what I needed !    The "check.names" argument set to FALSE is the solution.  I just tested it.